# Why is the backticks operator in Perl not working without the quotes on Windows?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I'm pretty new to Perl, so forgive me if the question is trivial.

At work I have got an assignment to create a script which would send out e-mails when other developers would miss the due date of their tasks. As whole thing would have to work on Windows, using Strawberry Perl, I have used windows command `date /T` to perform the date check. I have called external commands quite a lot, using the backticks operator, but in this particular case the backticks would not work:

```
my $date = `date /T`;
```

Outputs:

```
date: invalid date `/T'
```

Fixed using some additional quotes:

```
 my $date = `"date /T"`
```

Outputs:

```
Mon 07/07/2014
```

My question is: why is that?

I would get that if the other external calls with backticks would work the same, but that's the only one I have to call that way, to make it work.

Comment: It works for me without the quotes.

Comment: What happens when you exclude the quotes (aside from "not working")?

Comment: I'm running this as a script. Also sorry for missing the output of "not working". I somehow figured it's obvious. Noob mistake.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin? Under the command prompt, `date /T` works.  Under Cygwin, `date /T` gives `date: invalid date \`/T'`.

Comment: I actually am using Cmder with Cygwin and some of the GnuTools. When I'm entering the `date /T` in command prompt, I'm getting proper date. On script execution, I'm getting the `date: invalid date '/T'`.

Comment: It sounds like when you call it without quotes, it is pointed to cygwin's `date` executable based on cygwin's path. When you call it with quotes, it is using Window's date executable, based on your Windows path. Go into Cygwin and type `which date` or `type date` and you'll see that you are not using the Windows date.

Comment: Why don't you use a pure-Perl method of getting the date? e.g. `use Time::Piece; my $t = localtime; print $t->strftime('%a %d/%m/%Y');` This saves you from having to 1) check for errors in your external command, 2) worry about differences between external commands on different platforms, and 3) worry about annoying quoting issues.

Comment: I would use `Time::Piece` gladly, yet due to long story, and idiotic time format in our database, and system constraints it's not an option for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about those constraints? I'm just curious why a core module like `Time::Piece` wouldn't work, since it can produce the exact same output as the `date` command, without the issues I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Biggest "system" constraint is my manager, who actually want to get a grip on the code of the tool he is using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be accidentally using the Cygwin/GnuTools version of `date`.

Under a Windows command prompt, `date /T` gives the current time.
This is not an executable, this is a *command*.

However, running `date /T` under the Cygwin/GnuTools environment gives `date: invalid date '/T'`.
This is because the environment **1)** cannot see the Windows `date` *command* and **2)** finds a `date` *executable* in their `PATH` environment variable and runs it instead.